# Django 2.0 Admin "Add", filter by foreign key in another model

Tags: django

In a project I'm working on for a little office building, I have models that include `Floors`, `Locations`, down to `Assets` (workstations and printers and such):

```
class Floor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    floornumber = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Location(models.Model):
    fkfloor = models.ForeignKey(Floor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isroom = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    serialnumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Workstation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    asset = models.OneToOneField(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

In the Admin interface, I need a way for adding `Workstations` in the OneToOne relationship with `Assets`, but with a filter for the location so that the entire list of `Assets` (including non-workstations) in every part of the building doesn't show up in the admin Add/Change form for `Workstations`.

I've read through two books and searched SO and Django docs for every combination of terms I can think of for what I'm trying to accomplish, and I haven't found a working solution yet. I can use `list_filter` just fine to show the existing items, but that doesn't carry over into the admin add/change form. `inlines` aren't what I'm looking to use.

What concept am I missing here? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got stubborn and figured it out after another few hours of Googling. So for the good of all humanity searching for this, I shall post it all. It's a very hacked method, but no doubt could be refactored DRY. (Note: Cross-posted from my same question on Reddit).

My classes remain nearly the same as above, but I added Buildings as a FK to Floors. Not that I have more than one building IRL, but it helped narrow down the test data with some contrived things. "ef" is just my prefix for "extra field".

```
#admin.py
class AssetForm(forms.ModelForm):
  efbuilding = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Building.objects.all(),label=u"Building",required=False)
  effloor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Floor.objects.all(),label=u"Floor",required=False)
  class Meta:
    fields = '__all__'
    model = Asset
class AssetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
form = AssetForm
fieldsets = (
    (None, {
       'fields': ('efbuilding','effloor','fklocation'), #The 'extra' fields from above
    }),
    ('Asset Information', {
        'fields': ('name','serialnumber', ...)
    }),
)
```

The fieldsets force the extra fields at the top of the Admin form, where they look quite natural. views.py and urls.py were next:

```
#views.py
from django.core import serializers
def addasset(request): # <-- note that this only needed "request". Putting something else there screwed things up.
  if request.method == 'GET':
    building_id = request.GET.get('id')
    json_floor = serializers.serialize("json", Floor.objects.filter(fkbuilding_id=building_id))
    return HttpResponse(json_floor) #Probably a terrible practice here with not using JsonResponse, but this worked
  else:
    return HttpResponse("No-go")

#urls.py (Needed to hook view, the URL doesn't really matter)
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  path('addasset/', views.addasset), #<-- later versions of Django use "path" instead of regular expressions
]
```

Instead of extending the Admin change_form.html, I made a copy of it to its own folder to replace it for this test so that I didn't lose my bearings on the template tags. As this could be documented more clearly, here's exactly how that works:

From the virtual environment directory, copy:

`/env_assettracker/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html`
...to a new directory inside the project (my project directory is in the env directory):
`/env_assettracker/assettracker/templates/admin/assetapp/asset/change_form.html`

In general terms, /PROJECT/templates/admin/APP/MODEL/change_form.html. This worked without having to add anything extra DIRS to the settings.py file.

At the bottom of the new copy of change_form.htmlin the last block after the script, I added my own scripts:

```
#change_form.html
{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
<script>...the existing script for in the template...</script>
//add jQuery from my static files
<script src="{% static "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" %}"></script>
```

First, since this is going to be using AJAX, I went with the Django recommended cookie method. The exact verbiage from their documentation worked fine. I pretty much copy-pasted their block of code into the beginning of my new script section.

Now for the good part:

```
#change_form.html
$(function() {
  ...all the csfr token / cookie stuff...
  $('#id_efbuilding').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/addasset/",{id: $(this).val()}, function(j) {
      var options = '<option value="">---??---</option>'; //blank value when nothing is selected in the box
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + parseInt(j[i].pk) + '">' + j[i].fields['name'] + '</option>';
      }
      $("#id_effloor").html(options);
      $("#id_effloor option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
    $("id_efbuilding").attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
```

This was my first attempt with jQuery and AJAX, so I'm sure that the requests are muddled between Http and JSON. Far from elegant, but it works. Selecting a building now changes the choices available in the floors, and then I guess I'll make another one after that to change the locations, and then the same methodology should apply to the one-to-one models (though I'll try to put the code in a more reusable place).

These were compiled from multiple sources. The most helpful was an old blog post from 2009 [here](https://formerlyconversal.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/dynamic-select-fields-with-jquery-and-django/).

And with that, I should probably eat something.